# Loading data from BigQuery to Salesforce

Tags: google-bigquery, salesforce

I have two datasources - Salesforce(SF) and BigQuery(BQ). All the data from SF is available in BQ.

**So my question is can we load data from BQ to SF?**.

Here's what I want to achieve -

I want to do some calculation in BQ using SF data fields and create 3/4 new fields in BQ. And then I want to load these new fields into SF in respective objects (e.g. Lead, Opportunities, etc.). Once I have these new fields in SF, I can then create reports/dashboards in SF.

**So is loading data from BQ to SF possible?** .

While I can create these fields in SF as well; but due to some limitation this is currently not possible. So thought of doing it in a reverse way?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes this is possible.

You have a couple of options available to implement this. 
For example you can interact with BigQuery using "Salesforce Connect", or you use the BigQuery connector.

The following explains in detail the use of Salesforce Connect [Salesforce Connect](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/platform_connect_about.htm), here you can review the use and implementation of [Google BigQuery Connection](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_integrate_connectors_googlebigquery_settings.htm&type=5)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, the question is quite old. But the world has moved on, so there are easier options today.

You should definitely check out a reverse etl solution. For example like https://www.getcensus.com/.

Here you can set up automatic syncs between BigQuery and Salesforce. The setup is quite straightforward.